# Adjusting Context when using rallystandardreport

Tags: rally, code-rally

I'm utilizing the rally standard report to generate an iteration burndown, but given that i want post this on a wiki/web page. Looking for a way to point this to a project/subproject so that I can have several instances of this on one page. I tried it via context, but I'm obviously missing something. The code is below, any guidance/recommendation would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Mark

```
    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    context : {
            workspace : 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/50876644101',
            project : 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/50891172431'
           },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'rallystandardreport',
        width: 750,
        height: 500,
        reportConfig: {
           report: 'IterationBurndown',
           subchart: 'hide',
           title : 'IterationBurndown',
           project : 'Harrier'
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody().dom
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  The StandardReport component was one of the earliest ones written and so it doesn't quite follow the standard ability to pass in a context like most of the rest of the SDK.

You're on the right path with the [project](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport-cfg-project) config above- it just needs to be the ref of the project you're targeting rather than the name, and it goes right on the root component config instead of beneath reportConfig.  There are also [projectScopeUp](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport-cfg-projectScopeDown) and [projectScopeDown](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.report.StandardReport-cfg-projectScopeDown).

There's also a full example here: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/example/standard-report

```
{
    xtype: 'rallystandardreport',
    width: 750,
    height: 500,
    reportConfig: {
       report: 'IterationBurndown',
       subchart: 'hide',
       title : 'IterationBurndown'
    },
    project: '/project/12345',
    projectScopeUp: false,
    projectScopeDown: true
}
```